Service Principal (Federated Credentials) Get ACR Authorized Token
I'm trying to figure out how to obtain an authorized token to execute a Docker login to my Azure Container Registry (ACR), this command:
docker login ableacr.azurecr.io --username 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 --password [token]

I created a Service Principal with federated credentials, but when I request the ACR token, I receive the error:
AADSTS500011: The resource principal named "https://ableacr.azurecr.io" was not found in the tenant named "[My Tenant Name].

I've confirmed that my login with Entra ID is correct, as I'm able to read my service information via the Graph API. However, I'm unsure how to obtain the token for my ACR. As shown in the images, I have the appropriate role assignment for my ACR. I use Node.js to achieve this, and here is my code snippet:
async retrieveFederatedAccessTokenAsync(credentials: FederatedCredentials) {
        const authenticatedCredential = new ClientAssertionCredential(
            credentials.tenantId,
            credentials.appId,
            async () => credentials.ssoToken,
        );

        const accessToken = await authenticatedCredential.getToken('https://ableacr.azurecr.io/.default');
}


I also have access to the Azure Container Registry (ACR) since I connect using the ContainerRegistryManagementClient, which retrieves the correct information about my ACR:
const authenticatedCredential = new ClientAssertionCredential(
            credentials.tenantId,
            credentials.appId,
            async () => credentials.ssoToken,
        );

        const acrClient = new ContainerRegistryManagementClient(authenticatedCredential, 'my-azure-subscription-id');
        for await (const registry of acrClient.registries.list()) {
            console.log(registry);
        }

Response:
{
  id: '/subscriptions/[my-azure-subscriotion-id]/resourceGroups/rg-able/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/ableacr',
  name: 'ableacr',
  type: 'Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries',
  location: 'westus',
  tags: {},
  ...

I also noticed that the Service Principal can configure API permissions, but when I try to find anything related to ACR, I couldn't find anything specific regarding the Pull Role.

Could you please help me understand how to get the token or what I need to configure in my Service Principal to achieve this?
Update:
I am not very familiar with how Azure works, but when I call a token using the code below, it retrieves a token that, when passed to the exchange URL of ACR, provides a final token allowing me to execute a Docker login. Is there a simpler way to generate a token for ACR or other Azure resources using service principal federated credentials?
const authenticatedCredential = new ClientAssertionCredential(
     credentials.tenantId,
     credentials.appId,
     async () => credentials.ssoToken,
);
    
const scope = `https://management.azure.com/.default`;
const accessToken = await authenticatedCredential.getToken(scope);

Exchange URL:
curl --location 'https://ableacr.azurecr.io/oauth2/exchange' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=access_token' \
--data-urlencode 'service=ableacr.azurecr.io' \
--data-urlencode 'tenant=[my-tenant-id]' \
--data-urlencode 'access_token=[token]'

